# Custom Yii2 validator not firing

Tags: yii2

I have custom form where I am trying to write a custom validator, but its not firing. The model is returned as valid every time submit button is hit:

```
class DeactivateForm extends Model {

    public $deactivate_reason;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [ 'deactivate_reason', 'reasonValidator' ],
        ];
    }

    public function reasonValidator( $attribute, $params ) {
        $this->addError( 'deactivate_reason', 'Error !!!' );
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'deactivate_reason' => 'Reason for deactivating',
        ];
    }
}
```

The actual form is plain jane:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin( [
    'id' => 'deactivate-form'
] );
```

When using `[ 'deactivate_reason', 'required' ]` in the rules, the required rule works fine, custom rule is still ignored...

Comment: Is it server or client side? Are you sending this field empty?

Comment: It is not sent empty

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but to forcefully run validation on empty field, add following property.

> skipOnError=>false and skipOnEmpty=>false

```
[
  ['deactivate_reason', 'reasonValidator',  'skipOnError' => false,'skipOnEmpty'=>false],
]
```

Comment: I tried that already, but tried again just in case, it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this,add return like below

```
public function reasonValidator( $attribute, $params ) {
   return $this->addError( 'deactivate_reason', 'Error !!!' );
}
```

Comment: according to the documentation, you do not need the return. In either case it did not make a difference

Comment: yes,documentation not specfied this,it's work when call this function in controller.And you tried ajax validation. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html